# I am getting a error for CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC .I have Any advice?

Tags: java

```
package com.writeAndRead;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;  
public class Read {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("excel.xls"));
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);   
        }
        if (row.getCell(1).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            System.out.println(row.getCell(1).getDateCellValue());
        }
    }
}
```

error: CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC cannot be resolved or is not a field.

I have tried reducing it to just NUMERIC but I GOT THE SAME PROBLEM.

Comment: Try and improve your question as it not proper and does not explain your query at all.

Comment: @Nathan Moniz Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Nathan Moniz Looks like there is an additional closing bracket before your 'if' statement. Also, check the Apache POI version you are using.

Comment: Isn't it `CellType.NUMERIC` instead of `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for the comments. I solved the issue myself. The `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` is now just `NUMERIC`. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

later version of Apache POI **poi-4.0.1** should Change your if condition from `HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` to `NUMERIC`

like this :

```
if (row.getCell(1).getCellType() == NUMERIC) {
            System.out.println(row.getCell(1).getDateCellValue());
```